# Forecasting a skewed series

Tags: time-series, distributions, python, forecasting, skewness

I am trying to forecast the following series.
The grey line is the forecast and the black line is the actual. I want a similar pattern in the forecast as we se ein the actuals .. for this particular series the percentage goes up at the end of the year. Is there a way to effectively do this in python.
[image]

Comment: You've got very strong periodicity and if you remove these recurring spikes, you've essentially got the line `y=0`. One option would be to use a non-parametric model, specifically Gaussian Process Regression. In this design you can use various kernels to compute the similarity of any two arbitrary points. There are kernels well adapted to periodic events such as this.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @jbuddy_13 . I chose to go another route to solve my original forecasting problem. Maybe I could revisit this later (since I am not very completely sure how to exactly implement what you suggested)